# Windows default size for console application

Tags: windows, command-line, console, cmd

While testing a console app, I set the properties of the console window to be only 3 lines high.

This change has somehow stuck, meaning that new console windows default to 3 lines high. If I create a new shortcut on the desktop, and point it to cmd.exe, the window that opens is 3 lines high.

Of course, I can alter this value using the properties panel, which ultimately results in "current window only"/"future windows with same title"/"shortcut that started this window" dialog to alter the stickiness of the setting. None of these choices results in the default being changed. If, subsequently, I make a new shortcut to cmd.exe, it's still 3 lines high.

The principal problem is that for any new console app that I write, the first time I debug it, I must change the size setting, and when I run the release build, it's the same story.

Does anyone know where the default settings for new (i.e. new title or from new shortcut) console app are stored/how to change them?

[and, yes, I feel like a muppet for asking, but I can't find this info anywhere!]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Instead of using the Properties menu item - Use the defaults menu item.

Comment: Also accessible through `control console.dll`

Answer (score 15):

They're stored in the Registry:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console
```